# Spring Security: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

The following config (filterChain) works fine in SpringBoot-2.7.5, but after I tried to test it in SpringBoot-3.0.0-RC1, it is not working and shows the following message, anything I need to change if want to migrate to Spring-Boot-3.0.0. Thanks.

> {
> "timestamp": 1667794247614,
> "status": 401,
> "error": "Unauthorized",
> "message": "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext",
> "path": "/api/admin/1" }

```
 @Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationProvider).and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()            
        // private endpoints
        .anyRequest().authenticated();

    http.addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    return http.build();
}
```

The following is the jwtTokenFilter:

```
@Component
public class **JwtTokenFilter** extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;
    
    @Autowired
    private JPAUserDetailService jpaUserDetailService;

    

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Get authorization header and validate
        final String header = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        
        if (isEmpty(header) || !header.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        // Get jwt token and validate
        final String token = header.split(" ")[1].trim();
        
        if (!jwtTokenUtil.validate(token)) {
                                    
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            
            return;
        }

        // Get user identity and set it on the spring security context
        UserDetails userDetails = jpaUserDetailService.loadUserByUsername(jwtTokenUtil.getUsername(token));

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, (userDetails == null ? null : userDetails.getAuthorities()));

        
        authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Spring Security 6, the default behavior is that the `SecurityContextHolderFilter` will only read the `SecurityContext` from `SecurityContextRepository` and populate it in the `SecurityContextHolder`. Users now must explicitly save the `SecurityContext` with the `SecurityContextRepository` if they want the `SecurityContext` to persist between requests. This removes ambiguity and improves performance by only requiring writing to the `SecurityContextRepository` (i.e. `HttpSession`) when it is necessary.

```java
SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
securityContextRepository.saveContext(securityContext, httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
```

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration.html#_explicit_save_securitycontextrepository

If that doesn't work, try going back to the 5.x default:

```java
http
    .securityContext((securityContext) -> 
            .requireExplicitSave(false)
    )
```

Comment: I changed the code to your last update codes, but still not work, would you please to give me a complete configuration in Spring Security 6? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I figure the solution for this problem.

As you can see in the spring security 6.x mentions:

> The SecurityContextHolderFilter is responsible for loading the
> SecurityContext between requests using the SecurityContextRepository.

And:

> SecurityContextHolder with a SecurityContext also saves the
> SecurityContext to the SecurityContextRepository if it should be
> persisted between requests.

So I add the SecurityContextHolderRepository into SecurityFilterChain:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig{

    @Resource(name = "jwtService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter(){
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository(){
        return new NullSecurityContextRepository(); // I use Null Repository since I don't need it for anything except store information in UserDetails
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.cors().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/auth/n/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/api/auth/r/testing").permitAll() // The API need JWT for authentication
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .securityContext((securityContext) -> securityContext.securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository())) // Add Security Context Holder Repository
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class); // Add it before UserName and Password AuthenticationFilter
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

And then in my custom Jwt Filter I save the SecurityContext into the NullContextRepository and problems solved:

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthenticationFilter.class);

    @Resource
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Resource
    private JwtUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Resource
    private SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String jwt = getJwtFromRequest(request);

        if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(jwt)){
            jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwt);
            String userName = jwtTokenUtil.getUserNameFromToken(jwt);
            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userName);

            if (userDetails != null && userDetails instanceof CustomUserDetails) {
                Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());

                SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
                securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);
                SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);

                securityContextRepository.saveContext(securityContext, request, response); // ADD this 
                LOG.info("Authentication has user name : " + ((UserDetails)authentication.getPrincipal()).getUsername());
            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String getJwtFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request){
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if(bearerToken == null){
            return null;
        }
        if(bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")){
            return bearerToken.substring(7);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]